# Calling a native function within a UDF in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions, bigquery-udf

I am trying to convert our legacy functions into standard SQL and so by using UDFs as a gig to reuse the old function names with the native functions.

Here I have my UDF to_char and inside use the parameters to run FORMAT_DATE but when I execute it even though a routine is created I get errors with no additional info.
Once the rountine has been created and I comment out the code the errors come as such *function to_char not found*

If I run a `CREATE TEMP FUNCTION` I get really long loading times(ca 30 - 90secs) and that obviously cant be right.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mytable.TO_CHAR(dstamp DATETIME, fmt STRING)
RETURNS STRING AS
(
    FORMAT_DATE(fmt, dstamp)
);

SELECT
    TO_CHAR(End_Time, 'yyyy-mm') AS Month_and_Year,
```

I don't want to create a temp function. Ideally I'd like to have a routine that I can just keep calling when need be but I am messing something up with my UDF and the FORMATE_DATE function. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

btw running this in GBQ.

Comment: why not just use built-in function as is ? FORMAT_DATE? Also, are you aware - you can create permanent functions? what is your real use case? please elaborate ...

Comment: I have a bunch of legacy code that we want to mode over to standard SQL and so instead of changing the functions to the built in ones I want to create my own for example the to_char function that does essentially the same thing using FORMAT_DATE. Yeah I know, wont a CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create a permanent function??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need reference UDF with dataset prefix, otherwise BigQuery think it is a builtin function or temporary UDF. In your case, just change `TO_CHAR` to `mytable.TO_CHAR`. Assuming your `mytable` is actually a dataset.

```
SELECT mytable.TO_CHAR(End_Time, 'yyyy-mm') AS Month_and_Year,
```